# Efficiently iterate in cell

Tags: matlab, iteration, cell

How do I iterate efficiently in a cell?

I've a cell like this:

```
H{i,j} = 

{1} {2} {3} {4} ...
{5} {6} {7} {8} ...
....
```

The actual dimension is ~300*300, with only ~1000 non-empty items.

```
for i = 1 : numel(H)
    if isempty(H{i}), continue, end
    for j = 1 : numel(H)
        if i==j || isempty(H{j}), continue, end
            COMPLEX_OPERATION(H{i}, H{J});
        end
    end
end
```

It's a two-layered(forgive my English) iteration on a single cell.

This code turned out to be in-efficient.

[image]

Too much time is wasted in the iteration.

**I'm trying to find an efficient way to perform this iteration.**

One possible solution is using cellfun(@COMPLEX_OPERATION), but I'm not sure how to perform this double-loop using cellfun.

A other possible solution is to prune empty cells at first. However I'm not sure whether this will address the problem in a large extend.

Comment: YOu are looping over your data and only if both elements (`H{i}` and `H{j}`) are not empty you want to do `COMPLEX_OPERATION()`, all the other times you want to do nothing. But you dont want to do `COMPLEX_OPERATION(H{i}, H{i});`. What about doing `COMPLEX_OPERATION(H{i}, H{j});` and later `COMPLEX_OPERATION(H{j}, H{i});`you want to do both?

Comment: It is not clear how you're storing your data. It is possibly not an efficient way to begin with. Solving the way you store it, would solve most of your current and future problems. If every cell has a scalar, then there is no reason to use cell arrays at all.

Comment: I agree. You shouldn't use cell arrays for single values. Also, you shouldn't use `i` and `j` as variables as those are used to represent complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should also be interesting. Use a double call to cellfun to get all combinations. Just change C1+C2 by your complex_function

```
%simulation
H=cell(300,300);
indx=randperm(numel(H));
[H{indx(1:1000)}]=deal(1);

%code you want
empty_H=cellfun(@isempty, H);
non_empty_H=H(~empty_H);
all_combinations=cellfun(@(C2) (cellfun(@(C1) C1+C2, non_empty_H, 'UniformOutput', false)), non_empty_H, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Just note that this will make 1000 more combinations (i==j) than you require (on the contrary to the for loops). Nonetheless, it may improve due to the use of cellfun. If necessary you can easily remove this at the inner cellfun with loss of interpretation of the combinations

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do

```
ind = ~cellfun(@isempty, H).* ~eye(size(H))

ind =

   0   1
   0   0

[r,c] = find(ind==1);
cellfun(@(H,r,c) (whatever_your_complex_function_does), H{[find(ind==1)].'}, cell2mat(r,[1 1]),cell2mat(c,[1 1]);
```

**A longer explanation...**

```
H ={[],[1 2]; [] [3 4]}



ind = cellfun(@isempty, H)

ind =

   1   0
   1   0
```

Those are you empty indices. We will invert them at the end.

Next, find those where `i=j`. We will then exclude them at the end.

Create an identiy matrix that represents the `i=j`.

```
I = eye(size(ind))

I =   

   1   0
   0   1
```

Then multiply those with the ind. We use `~I` so that we get the ones where `i~=j` and `(~ind)` so that we get the non-empty elements.

```
(~ind).*~I

ans =

0   1
0   0
```

Now you have got the indices where `H` are not empty and `i~=j`.

Get the subscripts for those.

```
[r,c] = find(ind==1);
```

Then you create an anonymous function that takes the values of `H` that corresponds to those subscripts and apply it element-wise to `H`. `H`, `r` and `c` will be used as inputs to the anonymous function where you can use it as `H{r}` or `H{c}`

```
cellfun(@(H,r,c) (whatever_your_complex_function_does), H{[find(ind==1)].'}, cell2mat(r,[1 1]),cell2mat(c,[1 1]);
```

Comment: I think he wants the `COMPLEX_OPERATION` of the each element with each other element (except the same). Thus by having `1000` non empty elements he would have 1,000,000 casts of `COMPLEX_OPERATION`. Could he solve this with `cellfun(@COMPLEX_OPERATION, H{indH}, H{indH})`? Would the `COMPLEX_OPERATION` be applied to n-th element with n-th element or to n-th element with each other element?

Comment: Updated to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly as @TheMinion says. The COMPLEX_OPERATION is not casted 1,000,000 times, if I were right.

Comment: I'm afraid my question is a little bit misleading. I'm actually looking forward to performing a double loop instead of an iteration among a single cell, as @TheMinion suggests. (His right on this part.)

Comment: @SolessChong I'm not sure what you mean by double loop but I've updated my answer to what I believe will reflect your pseudo code. There is only one call to `cellfun` that applies your COMPLEX_FUNCTION element-wise with your indices supplied.